# Compile .c library Eclipse for Android error

Tags: android, c, eclipse, android-ndk, android-library

I'm using Eclipse for Windows, Android SDK and Android NDK (I'm sure that all paths are set correclty).

I'm looking for compiling a .c library locatad in jni folder, but some error occur. This library depends on external .so libraries, these are my Makefile, Android.mk and library:
[jni folder](https://github.com/MattBon/Eclipse_project/tree/master/TravisBeatDetection/jni).

**Android.mk** :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

 #---------------------------------------------------------------

 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE := pdbeatdetection
 LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)\C:\PROGRAMMING\pd-0.45-4\src
 LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DPD
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := pdbeatdetection.c
 LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(LOCAL_PATH)\C:\PROGRAMMING\PdCore\libs\armeabi\ -lpdnative
 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Makefile** :

```
all:
C:\PROGRAMMING\android-ndk-r10d\ndk-build.cmd
mkdir ../tmp
cp ..\libs\armeabi\libpdBeatDetection.so ..\tmp\pdbeatdetection.pd_linux
cd ..\tmp && zip externals.zip *.pd_linux && mv externals.zip ..\res\raw
rm -rf ..\tmp
```

I followed some tutorials, but I'm not still able to solve this issue.
Could you please give me suggestions to compile the library, avoiding the following error?

**ERROR**:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libpdbeatdetection.so] Error 1 Discoteque C/C++ Problem
```

Thank you!

Comment: `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)\C:\PROGRAMMING\pd-0.45-4\src` looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

If your code depends on an external .so file, you should declare it properly using the `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` macro, like so:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#dependency
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := pdnative
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := C:/PROGRAMMING/PdCore/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libpdnative.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := C:/PROGRAMMING/pd-0.45-4/src
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#your module
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := pdbeatdetection
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := pdbeatdetection.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DPD
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If that's not enough to solve your issue, give us the error reported by calling `ndk-build.cmd` directly.